# Trouble installing CudaSift

Tags: c++, include, g++, sift

I just moved to C++ from Python.
I'm using VSCode and I'd like to use the following library: https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift .

So I clone the repo, make a build folder inside, cd to the build folder, use: `cmake ..`
then `sudo make` and finally `sudo make install` I get the following output in console:

[image]

After completing these steps, I get a shared library file called 'cudasift'.

From what I understand, I must then compile my code, which is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cudaImage.h>
#include <cudaSift.h>

int main(){
    SiftData siftData;
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::imread("Cam_0-19129655-STATIC-exp:200-gain:27.jpg").convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);

    CudaImage cuda_img;
    // cuda_img.Allocate(4000, 3000, 4000, false, NULL, (float*) cuda_img.d_data);

    // cuda_img.Download();

    int numOctaves = 5;
    float initBlur = 1.0f;
    float thresh = 3.5f;
    float minScale = 0.0f;
    bool upScale = false;

    // ExtractSift(siftData, cuda_img, numOctaves, initBlur, thresh, minScale, upScale);

    // FreeSiftData(siftData);

    return 0;
}
```

So I should run something like:
`g++ test.cpp -o test 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs' -I/path/to/my/headers -L/path/to/my/shared/library -lmylib`

The problem being: my newly obtained shared library is called 'cudasift', but -lmylib will look for a file called 'libmylib.so', so I rename my library to 'libcudasift.so', and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Documents/packages/CudaSift/build/libcudasift.so: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 13 (max 0)
/home/user/Documents/packages/CudaSift/build/libcudasift.so: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

I then remain stuck here after spending hours searching for an answer.
PS: I use VSCode

Comment: You have neither compiled or linked anything that contains the undefined references. The CMake installation built an executable program, not a library, and no library was installed.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your answer, I don't get it, how am I supposed to install the library then? Shouldn't I use the provided CMakeLists ?

Comment: It actually installed a file called 'cudasift', of type: Shared library