# Installing CudaSift on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, sift

I am having trouble installing the following [CudaSift library](https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift%20on%20Ubuntu%2018.04).

I downloaded it, built it and installed it with CMake as described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074229/trouble-installing-cudasift).

However I do not know what should I include in my Makefile in order to compile mainSift.cpp?

I already tried something like:

```
"g++" mainSift.cpp -o SiftCUDA `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` -L. -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include `pkg-config --libs opencv4` -lcudasift
```

but it resulted in -lcudasift not being found.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.46.

EDIT:

This is the Install_manifest from CMake:

```
/usr/local/./cudaImage.cu
/usr/local/./cudaImage.h
/usr/local/./cudaSiftH.cu
/usr/local/./cudaSiftH.h
/usr/local/./matching.cu
/usr/local/./cudaSiftD.h
/usr/local/./cudaSift.h
/usr/local/./cudautils.h
/usr/local/./geomFuncs.cpp
/usr/local/./mainSift.cpp
/usr/local/./cudaSiftD.cu
/usr/local/./CMakeLists.txt
/usr/local/data/left.pgm
/usr/local/data/righ.pgm
```

I do not see any .so library or so.

EDIT:

I have been able to execute mainSift by going to the installation directory CudaSift-Pascal and executing:

`./build/cudasift`

Now I would like to import in my own program the header files included in MainSift, namely:

```
#include "cudaImage.h"
#include "cudaSift.h"
```

Both headers were installed under /usr/local so I included -I/usr/local/ in my makefile and I also added /usr/local/ to "includePath" in c_cpp_properties.json.

However when I try to call the function InitCuda I get the following error

```
Warning: undefined reference to »InitCuda(int)«
```

Comment: Can you find the installed `cudasift` library on your system. Is it actually located in the location you tell the linker to look (i.e. `/usr/local/cuda/lib`)?

Comment: @squareskittles nothing is in there. I have edited the question with the output from the cmake install_manifest. Any ideas on how to proceed?